# IAM Role for Terragrunt

Tags: amazon-iam, terragrunt

I am reviewing this website, https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

where they discuss an IAM role for Terragrunt as in the following code

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/terragrunt"
  }
}
```

Which IAM Policy or Policies do I attach to the Terragrunt role?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `terragrunt` role is for deployments: Terragrunt have a [doc on this](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/aws-auth/).

Assuming you're using an s3 bucket for state:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BucketName>"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BucketName>/\*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**note**: *if using Dynamodb to *lock* `apply`'s, you'll need to add that too (documented on that same page); the same applies for KMS*

The above policy is the least permissive, not including actions such as `s3:CreateBucket`.